# Graph library that supports edge labels

Tags: c, perl, graph

I stumbled across [Perl's Graph library](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Graph-0.94/lib/Graph.pod) this morning. I used to write a quick program to find all (weakly) connected components in a directed graph. Here is the program.

```
use strict;
use Graph;
use Data::Dumper;

my $g = Graph->new();
foreach my $file(@ARGV)
{
  open(my $IN, "<", $file) or die("cannot open '$file'");
  while(my $line = <$IN>)
  {
    chomp($line);
    my($source, $target, $edge_label) = split(/\t/, $line);
    $g->add_edge($source, $target);
  }
  close($IN);
}

my @clusters = $g->weakly_connected_components();
print Dumper(\@clusters);
```

...and the input data files look like this.

```
n1  n2  some_data_encoded_in_a_label
n1  n3  some_data_encoded_in_a_label
n4  n5  some_data_encoded_in_a_label
...
```

...where the first column is the source node label, the second column is the target node label, and the third column is an edge label. I have a couple of data files, each with tens of thousands of edges.

This quick-n-dirty script got the job done, but there were a few things that would have been nice to have.

- The connected components returned by the **weakly_connected_components** method were simply arrays of node labels, so the connections between these nodes is lost.
- Even if the method returned a set of nodes *and* a set of edges, the library does not permit storage of labels or data associated with each edge, which is inconvenient.

Are there any alternative graph libraries that include either or both of these features? The language of implementation is not very important--I'm open to C/C++, Python, Perl, R, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 $g->add_edge($source, $target);
```

to (zero or one label per edge)

```
 $g->add_edge($source, $target);
 $labels{$source}{$target} = $edge_label;
```

or (any number of labels per edge)

```
 $g->add_edge($source, $target);
 push @{ $labels{$source}{$target} }, $edge_label;
```

And just lookup the label when you need it.

(For undirected graphs, add each label twice, once for source->target and once for target->source.)

Comment: +1 Yeah, I guess this is a decent workaround for the second issue. I'd really be interested if there was a way to get not only the nodes but also the edges of each connected component.

Comment: Also, since this is a directed graph, you would only want to add the label once. The edge from A -> B is not the same as the edge from B -> A, and would have a different label.